# Django: Instantiate object with `null` ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have two models in my application, `A`, `B`.

`A` is supposed to have a one-to-many relationship with `B`, so `B` carries a `ForeignKey` attribute to `A`.

The relationships however are only establishing after a while, *not* when objects of `B` are instantiated. I understand from the documentation that in this case, I'm supposed to use `null=True` as an argument to the ForeignKey of `B`. The `B` table indeed looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "B" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "applied_with_id" integer REFERENCES "A" ("id")
)
;
```

In my `B` model, I set the `applied_with` field as

```
applied_with = models.ForeignKey('A', null=True)
```

as shown in the Django documentation using a string parameter for the referenced model.

Note that the `NOT NULL` constraint in `applied_with_id` is absent by using `null=True`.

However, when I now go about and create a `B` object, I get

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: B.applied_with_id may not be NULL
```

I can't understand the reason for this and also, how else does one create one-to-many relationships where the connections only establish after a while?
I checked related posts about `null` ForeignKeys here but the only related post seems to be one where `updatedb` solves the problem (without any model changes). I'm using Django 1.5 and have used the equivalent `syncdb` but without any success.

Comment: Are you sure that's the current state of the table? Remember `syncdb` doesn't change existing tables, and `sqlall` shows what the table *would* look like if you created it now, not what it does actually look like.

Comment: I just reproduced the error. I deleted the database, recreated it and checked to find `"applied_with_id" integer REFERENCES "A" ("id")`. Is the only solution to delete and recreate the database?

Comment: Check your database vendor's syntax for how to remove NOT NULL constraints from existing tables (likely found from ALTER TABLE documentation). Also, in Django 1.7 migrations feature should be able to handle this automatically for you.

Comment: It's SQLite 3 so should be as indicated in the post.